# Can not start java web start

Tags: java, java-7, java-web-start

I have typed `javaws url_of_jnlp` in my CMD under windows 7, but i got the following error:-

```
CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: url_of_jnlp]
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have noticed this problem since i need java web start to be able to run an application, but when i tired to run this application , i will be asked to save a file named webstart.jnlp , instead of automatically lunching the java web start.

So what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `url_of_jnlp` with the actual url of the jnlp file of the application.

This will not work: `javaws url_of_jnlp`

This will work: `javaws "C:\..[Path to folder]..\My_Application.jnlp"`

You should really have found this info yourself, it is available at the bottom of this page:
http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml

See this page for info on command line options for javaws: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/javaws.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the following links to make sure everything is perfect in your setup.

[Common Java Web Start Problems](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/deployment/webstart/problems.html)

[Deploying Java Web Start Applications](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am afraid that this problem is related to the fact that i am having two java versions under the java folder one for the "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06" while the other for "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7". But i need these two versions to be able to work on other applications.